# How can I remap Ctrl-backspace in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, backspace

I'm trying to map Ctrl-backpace to `kill-whole-line in emacs but no such luck.
I've tried:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-\d") 'kill-whole-line)
```

and

```
(global-set-key "\C-\d") 'kill-whole-line)
```

but they have either given me Lisp errors or just plain don't work.
Maybe my syntax is wrong?

Thanks,
-Adam

Comment: For any key binding at all, you can just *ask Emacs*: `C-h k KEY` (or `C-h c KEY`) tells you a name that you can use with `kbd`. In this case: `(global-set-key (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'kill-whole-line)`. You never have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(global-set-key [C-backspace] 'kill-whole-line)
```

Comment: Flawless victory. Thanks!!